# DD-WRT bandwidth divide between 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz band

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, bandwidth

I have just flashed DD-WRT firmware in place of my TP-Link Archer C7's stock firmware.

I have turned on both bands. I can't use only the 5 GHz band because some devices don't support it. I have 100 Mbps connection. After setting it up, at first, I thought that I was only getting 50 Mbps due to poor connection, etc.

But after turning off 2.4 GHz, I noticed that the WAN bandwidth was dividing between both bands (50 Mbps + 50 Mbps). However on stock firmware, it wasn't the case.

How can I make it so the WAN bandwidth is not divided between both bands this way?

Comment: It's very unlikely that there's a "hard split". How did you test the bandwidth? How is wired performance?

Comment: Speedtest.net. When I connect to router with ethernet and I do speedtest, I get 100 Mbps. But when I connect with 5 ghz wifi, I get 50-51 Mbps. That's divided bandwidth. Also, when I disable 2.5 ghz on router, I get 100 Mbps full speed with 5 ghz band.

Comment: You are always going to get your full connection speed over an ethernet connection.  Wireless is going to be less then 100 Mbps.  What you describe is not possible.  For a router to even support 2.4 GHZ and 5 GHz it has to have two radios, which means, the bandwidth will not be "split" there wouldn't be a point.  There is something else going on here.  What 802.11 modes specifically are you using?  Are you 100% you have a 100 **Mbps** connection, units are important, I suspect your giving an incorrect unit to us.

Comment: I based that on the fact the 2.4 GHz capabilties of that router can support 450Mbps and the 5.0 GHz capabilites supports 1300Mbps which is 4.5x and 13x faster then even your getting on your ethernet connection **( which simply isn't possible ).**

Comment: @ramhound Yes it is. when I use stock firmware, I get full 99-100 Mbps speed. But the problem is with dd-wrt. 100 Mbps I mean 100 megabits  per second.